# If $\sum{c_n6^n}$ converges then what can you say about the following:

Tags: calculus

If $\sum{c_n6^n}$ converges then what can you say about the following:
$$\sum{c_n(-2)^n}$$
$$ \sum{c_n(-6)^n}$$

My answer:
$\sum{c_n(-2)^n}$ will converge but $ \sum{c_n(-6)^n}$ will not in all cases. At first I thought both of these were absolutely convergent but I found a counter example in the second case if $c_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n6^n}$

I am hoping someone will point out how to use a relevant test (ratio/root etc.) to show my conclusion (assuming its right).

Comment: There is information missing. Do you mean if $\sum{c_n6^n}$ *converges*?

Comment: yes: I made the edit.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. The $\limsup$ root test can show that the first series will converge, while your counterexample takes care of the second series.

Comment: In general is it true that if $\sum{c_n(a^n)}$ converges then $\sum{c_n}(-b)^n$ converges (where $|b|<|a|$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$. The radius of convergence of this series must be at least 6. This means that the series must converge for all $|z| < 6$. So it converges for $z = -2$.  Look up Cauchy-Hadamard formula for help with the reasoning.